# Splitting a Redis RDB file

Tags: caching, amazon-ec2, redis, redis-rdb

Currently I'm using redis on a EC2 machine, with 60G RAM without any slaves, but as my data grows I will need more memory.

I was thinking to migrate to 2 x 60G machines and split the already existing data between the two.

Is there any tool for splitting the RDB file? I haven't found anything specifically designed for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split your data, you will need to have a way to shard your keys so some keys will be written/read from server A and the others from server B

There is no way to split a RDB file, but there is something you can do to achieve what you want.

First what you can do is start a redis instance on your second server and say it is a slave of your current server, but set the param slave-read-only to false. This will cause the slave to synchronize and read all of your redis data from master. So far you only have a slave with all the data, but now we will do the interesting bit.

Then you need to decide on a sharding strategy. Some redis clients do this for you. For example, the official Ruby client knows how to handle that if you configure it. You will need to configure your client so keys will be sharded to A and B (or alternative use twemproxy so the clients won't know about different servers and the twemproxy will take care of it)

Once you have the clients configure, you need to deploy the new clients to production and immediately configure the slave as not a slave anymore. You can do this directly using the CONFIG command on the slave server (don't forget to persist the config using CONFIG REWRITE) or you can change the config file of the slave and restart, whatever is more convenient for you.  Since the slave is configured as slave-read-only false, it will accept writes even on slave mode. This means if you change the config directly from the redis-cli you can change from slave to just a sharded stand-alone redis without restarting, which I think is quite cool.

Be aware once you shard, you will have to be careful with MULTI commands or when using LUA scripts. If you are using twemproxy you won't be able to use those commands, but if you are sharding on the client side, you will still be able to use MULTI or LUA. Just be careful to use a sharding mechanism in which all the related keys will stay on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

step1: install https://github.com/leonchen83/redis-rdb-cli/
step2: create a config file to set spliting condition
content of `nodes.conf`

```
34b6e1dfb871ad30398ef5edd6b9a954617e6ec1 127.0.0.1:10003@20003 master - 0 1531044047088 3 connected 8193-16383
89d020a7e727e81f003836207902ae26fe05fd51 127.0.0.1:10001@20001 myself,master - 0 1531044047000 1 connected 0-8192
vars currentEpoch 6 lastVoteEpoch 0
```

step3: run `rdt -s your-dump.rdb -c nodes.conf -o /path/to`

after step3. that will generate 2 rdb files in `/path/to` directory `34b6e1dfb871ad30398ef5edd6b9a954617e6ec1.rdb` and `89d020a7e727e81f003836207902ae26fe05fd51.rdb`